# SQL combining multiple rows into a single comma separated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a list of users from the asp.net membership table.

i want to display user id, username, email and role name in a single line.

My statement is as follows

```
SELECT [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserId],
  [UserName],
  [Email],
  [RoleName]

FROM [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Users]

INNER JOIN [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership]

ON [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserId] = [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership].[UserId]

INNER JOIN [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles]

ON [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserId] = [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].[UserId]

Inner Join [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Roles]

On [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles].[RoleId] = [Dev].[dbo].[aspnet_Roles].[RoleId]
```

the results i get back are close to what i want, except that i am getting multiple rows back for the role names.

```
| UserID | UserName | Email | RoleName |
|--------|----------|-------|----------|
| 1      | Jon      | Jon@  | Author   |
| 1      | Jon      | Jon@  | Approver |
| 1      | Jon      | Jon@  | Admin    |
| 2      | Mary     | Mary@ | Author   |
| 2      | Jon      | Mary@ | Approver |
```

How do i get the multiple row names to display as a single line?

```
| UserID | UserName | Email | RoleName                  |
|--------|----------|-------|---------------------------|
| 1      | Jon      | Jon@  | Author, Approver, Admin   |
| 2      | mary     | mary@ | Author, Approver          |
```